# Service design on Docker machine

Tags: docker, service

There is the word "One service per machine". Is this still true when it comes to Docker? Or is it common / best practice to deploy containers with completely independent services (say: a Nexus Package Manager, a MantisBT bug tracker, a Dokuwiki and maybe even a complete Gitlab) on one Docker host?

Thanks and cheers,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would only deploy one service via docker on one host, Docker itself would be completely  useless.

In this context, one Docker container is "one machine".